# Is there an alternative to coverage for the unittest in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, unit-testing, python-unittest

I would like to know if it exists an alternative to the coverage package for the unittest in Django because I am looking for a tool which told me the number of functions, class which are covered.

Do you know if this kind of tools for Django exist ?

I knox for php there is phpunit which give this kind of metrics.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

how about nose, it can provide similar functionality -> https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/